# How to find group which is having Status Active?

Tags: sql, join, group-by, aggregate-functions, having-clause

I have a id which is having more than one Accountid in a table with status Active . I need to find group of active for the particular ID .

[image]

Please find my below query .is it correct or something need to modify to get better optimized result .

```
select id,count(Accountid) from CustomerAccount
where status='Active'
group by id
having count(*)>( select min(maxxount) from(
            select id,count(accountid) as maxxount
                        from CustomerAccount
                        group by id)A)
```

Comment: GIve some sample data and expected output based on that. If possible create a fiddle demo at sqlfiddle.com . Also mention the RDMS/version you are using

Comment: Are you trying to get the list of those Accounts which have more than 1 Active status entry?

Comment: @Utsav  for example : account id 1 and 5 having two  id with status active . can i get result of 1 and 5v . Above gives result but i can get very simplified way to find id having more than one active status .

Comment: @DEEPAKLAKHOTIA yes: you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query:

```
select id,count(Accountid) from CustomerAccount
where status='Active'
group by id
having count(*) >1
```

Comment: : ok thank you . gives me result

Comment: please give me up vote